# In my stored procedure I have 4 different tables select query I have to store this all table data in c# List<>

Tags: c#, t-sql, stored-procedures

My SQL stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTradeByLevel](
@LevelId INT                  
)
AS
BEGIN
if(@LevelId=1)
BEGIN
select * from CHANNELCLASS 
select a.* from accountmaster a join CHANNELCLASS b on        a.ChannelClassificationId=b.ChannelClassificationId 
select r.* from REGION r join accountmaster a on r.Accountid=a.AccountID 
select s.* from STORE s join REGION r on s.RegionID=r.RegionId
END
else if(@LevelId=2)
BEGIN
select a.* from accountmaster a join CHANNELCLASS b on  a.ChannelClassificationId=b.ChannelClassificationId
select r.* from REGION r join accountmaster a on r.Accountid=a.AccountID
select s.* from STORE s join REGION r on s.RegionID=r.RegionId
END
else if(@LevelId=3)
BEGIN
select r.* from REGION r join accountmaster a on r.Accountid=a.AccountID
select s.* from STORE s join REGION r on s.RegionID=r.RegionId
END
else if(@LevelId=4)
BEGIN
select s.* from STORE s join REGION r on s.RegionID=r.RegionId
END
END

GO
```

I have to call this stored procedure in C# console application. If my parameter value is 1 it means I have to store 4 table values in a C# `List<>`. I have tried, but it stores only the first table's data.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int v = 1;
        int cl;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=CTSINDLFVMOSS;Initial Catalog=DB_CGTPO_DEVE;User ID=DB_CGTPO_DEVE;Password=cgtpo");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetTradeByLevel", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LevelId", v);
        List<string> customers = new List<string>();
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            cl = dr.FieldCount;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < cl; i++)
                {
                    customers.Add(dr[i].ToString());
                    //customers.Add(dr[1].ToString());
                    //customers.Add(dr[2].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < customers.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
        {
            Console.WriteLine(customers[i]);
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    }
}
```

This is my console application page... if my parameter value is 1 mean it have to store 4 table values but it will taking first table value only i have to store all 4 table values 
any one help me,....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yupes NextResult()

example:

```
dim dr as sqldatareader = <your command that will return data>

while dr.read
'do stuff
end while

dr.NextResult()

while dr.read...
```

if you perform multiple selects in your stored procedure, all will be contained in the `SqlDataReader`, it's just your method of advancing the reader...

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/NextResult-in-C-or-ADONET-data-reader-705.php

Comment: hi...in console application the next() function is not available having only nextresult() but its showing error friend....

Comment: hay thanks its working but its taking ly 1st row values from al the tables but i want to display al rows from al the tables

Comment: Have a look at http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/NextResult-in-C-or-ADONET-data-reader-705.php

Comment: If you are satisfied with answer, please vote and accept answer.Thanks :)

Comment: Must confess I didn't know that. There again I'd sack myself if I designed something that relied on it. But have a vote anyway I learnt something.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to return multiple tables its better to use adapter to fill data set instead of command.execute reader.

for your scenario data set will be best option.

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds=new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds);
```

Then you can nevigate through ds.tables[1] or ds.tables[2].

Answer (score 0):

This is never going to work

Your SqlDataReader for level 1 is only going to see

```
select s.* from STORE s join REGION r on s.RegionID=r.RegionId
```

i.e. the last select statement executed in that logic path.

Either have one sp per result set, add another parameter, to get Level 1 result 1 etc. I would cream you if you did this at work...

Or you could try some sort of join / union, if applicable.

Back to drawing board.

Comment: if my parameter value is 1 means it will take first table(channel class) if 2 means it will take second table(accountmaster) like that its processing but i need to take all tables and i cant able to change in store procedure

Comment: if my parameter value is 1 means it will take first table(channel class) if 2 means it will take second table(accountmaster) like that its processing but i need to take all tables and i cant able to change in store procedure

Answer (score 0):

Tom told you truth. This will never working can you show your database and write what data you need?

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures with multiple result sets are a feature that many persistance frameworks don't support at all (which is a shame). I'm not sure if it's possible to do this using classic ADO.NET readers, but Linq2Sql does have full support for this scenario:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/05/linq-to-sql-stored-procedures-with-multiple-results-imultipleresults.aspx